# Why isn't there an article in "would you wanna grab coffee sometimes?"

Tags: articles

I came across this sentence recently and I’m really curious why there isn't an article before **coffee**. So here’s the sentence:

> You don’t need to text me back. I completely understand if you don’t want to talk to me. But on the off chance you do, would you wanna grab coffee sometimes?

Comment: BTW, the word **sometimes** there suggests multiple future visits to the coffee shop, rather than a single open-ended invitation.  It is idiomatic to **grab *a* coffee**; "grab coffee" strikes my ear as "off".

Comment: And "grab coffee sometimes" is definitely an unidiomatic combination.  "Grab" here denotes something ad hoc, spontaneous, spur-of-the-moment. It's like asking "Would you like to plan to run into each other accidentally now and then?"

Comment: "Grab coffee" sounds quite idiomatic to me, but "sometimes" should be "sometime" unless you really intend to suggest recurring events. In this context, a single possible event should be referred to by "sometime".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many foodstuffs are both countable and uncountable. All the following are idiomatic:

> Go for a coffee.
>
> Go for some coffee.
>
> Go for coffee.

The first one can only mean "Go and have a cup of coffee" (though it doesn't rule out having more than one!). The others usually mean that, but in context they could also mean "go and buy some ground coffee or coffee beans".